# Best way for repair files names?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to backup directory, but some file names are "corrupteds":

```
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/media/[...]/Ford transit/Porte v\#351lo Ford Transit.odg": Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character (84)
```

What is the best way to "repair" them ? (or replace corrupted character by '_' or '-' ...)

Comment: Are you using 2 encodings? Try this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/convmv.1.html     (convmv -f utf8 -t iso-8859-1 <filename>)

Comment: Hi, maybe, it's windows partition on computer what i backup for someone. convmv look like perfect, but encoding of files is 'binary': file -bi /media/disk/[...]/T�l�chargements/
inode/directory; charset=binary and convmw don't accept 'binary' as from charset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As like Rinzwind said, i've fix 90% of error names after find original charset:

```
sudo convmv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 -r /media/disk/*
```

Comment: Excellent :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the fly with RSync. I didn't even know I was getting this error because I run in CRON without verbose untill I set up [EMAILS FROM ROOT TO GMAIL](https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/2015/12/05/configure-emails-from-root-to-gmail-cron-messages/).

Then I was getting the same error.

```
 (Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character)
```

I added

```
--dry-run --iconv=iso-8859-1,utf8
```

and go no output, this is good. But again I tested with

```
--dry-run --iconv=iso-8859-1,utf8 -v
```

and read thru and saw no errors. So problem solved.

--dry-run                = doesn't actually do anything

--iconv=iso-8859-1,utf8  =--iconv=[localenc],[remoteenc] (Conv. Enc. on the fly)

-v                       = verbose output (w/o verbose only errors are output)